How to return all/multiple the Cell Addresses/Reference in Datagridview?
This is my new post but in continuation of Thread 78734244 of this forum.
I was wondering How Could i get all the Cell Addresses/Reference in Datagridview. The above thread was for
any single input of Cell Value to get its respective Cell Address in Datagridview.
Now I would like to have all Cell Addresses/References of DataGridView
ie for the below grid
6 9 7
8 1 5
2 4 3
and get list like below
6 is in cell (0,0)
9 is in cell (0,1)
7 is in cell (0,2)
8 is in cell (1,0)
1 is in Cell (1,1)
5 is in Cell (1,2)
2 is in Cell (2,0)
4 is in cell (2,1)
6 is in cell (2,2)
So in order to get the multiple cell reference
First i've Created numbers as List
Dim numbers As String() = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
and by searching the above nos i get the multiple cell.Address Reference of DataGridview
I don't know whether the below Function is Correct for the desired result.
After Getting the below list of all the Cell Address I would like to use the same cell Address for more datagridviews
What would you suggest to store the same in List or Array ?
Your help will be appreciated
Thanks SsD
Private Sub MultipleCells_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim cellsList As New ArrayList

        For i As Integer = 1 To UBound(numbers)
            Dim cell = mulitpleGetCellAddress(DataGridView1, numbers(i))
            If cell IsNot Nothing Then
                'MessageBox.Show($"Data exists in cell ({cell.RowIndex}, {cell.ColumnIndex})")
                cellsList.Add($"", i & ({cell.RowIndex}, {cell.ColumnIndex})) '& ({cell.RowIndex}, {cell.ColumnIndex}))
            Else
                'MessageBox.Show("Data does not exist!")
            End If
            'i = i + 1
        Next
End Sub 
Private Function mulitpleGetCellAddress(dgv As DataGridView, searchString As String) As DataGridViewCell
    For Each row In dgv.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)
        For Each cell In row.Cells.OfType(Of DataGridViewCell)
            If cell.Value.ToString() = searchString Then
                Return cell
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function

made a Blunder in the line 
```cellsList.Add($"", i & ({cell.RowIndex}, {cell.ColumnIndex})) '& ({cell.RowIndex}, {cell.ColumnIndex})) 

Hello
I am literally struggling with the result
I tried with below
Dim tpleNumbers = Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
Error Generates
Overload resolution failed because no accesible 'Create accepts this number of Arguments
Above Error starts because of above 9 elmenents as soon as I delete 9 from above. No Error I suppose Tuple only accepts 8 elements
6 9 7 8 1 5 2 4 3
How do I Achieve the Following Result for all the numbers
i.e. Data Exists in cells  6 (0,0); 9 (0,1); 7 (0,2); 8 (1,0); 1 (1,1); 5 (1,2); 2 (2,0) 4 (2,1); 3 (2,2)
How can I incorporate Reference of Numbers.Select(Function(n) $"{n}")) or cells.Select(Function(c) to get the above result
Do I change the Sequence from
Dim Numbers As String() = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
'to
Dim Numbers As String() = {"6", "9", "7", "8", "1", "5", "2", "4", "3"}

Using Below: The Co-ordinates of Each Cell has displayed beautifully in chronological order but without the Respective Cell Values
Dim cells = mulitpleGetCellAddress(DataGridView1, numbers.Select(Function(n) $"{n}"))
If cells IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show($"Data exists in cells {String.Join("; ", cells.Select(Function(c) $"({c.RowIndex}, {c.ColumnIndex})"))}")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Data does not exist!")
End If

Private Iterator Function mulitpleGetCellAddress(dgv As DataGridView, searchStrings As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of DataGridViewCell)
        For Each row In dgv.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)
            For Each cell In row.Cells.OfType(Of DataGridViewCell)
                If searchStrings.Any(Function(s) cell.Value.ToString() = s) Then Yield cell
            Next
        Next
    End Function 

Thanks

Hello. You've copied the answer to your previous question asking for new requirements. Now, did that answer solve your previous problem in the first place? Either accept that answer so one can help you to extend it or edit your question to tell us that it does not work for you and why.

dr.null as per Thread 78734244 the issue has been resolved. Although I continued for the same but as per forum rules I agreed and posted the new thread today in continuation . So wanted to get the cell references of all the cells in the DGV as per#1 of this thread. Ive ACCPETED by clicking on Up Arrow on Left of Thread 78734244 As Answer is usefful

@SsD I'm not looking for checkmarks, but that is not how you accept an answer. Hit the checkmark :)

Since we're iterating over a UI element, we would want to limit the number of iterations. Let's use an iterator function returning all the matches, with each cell only being checked once - well the Any will stop checking once a match is found and even though both your idea and this one are O(n2), this one is so to a lesser degree.
Private Iterator Function mulitpleGetCellAddress(dgv As DataGridView, searchStrings As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of DataGridViewCell)
    For Each row In dgv.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)
        For Each cell In row.Cells.OfType(Of DataGridViewCell)
            If searchStrings.Any(Function(s) cell.Value.ToString() = s) Then Yield cell
        Next
    Next
End Function

Now you will have a list of cells which match any of the sought items
Dim cells = mulitpleGetCellAddress(DataGridView1, numbers.Select(Function(n) $"{n}"))
If cells IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show($"Data exists in cells {String.Join("; ", cells.Select(Function(c) $"({c.RowIndex}, {c.ColumnIndex})"))}")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Data does not exist!")
End If


djv Thanks for your reply. The MessasgBox.show displays asData exists in cells (0,0);(0,1);(0,2);(1,0);(1,1);(1,2);(2,0);(2;1);(2,2) Rather than showing as Data 6 exists in cell(0,0) & vbcrlf **&   Data 9 exsits in (0,1) etc i was expecting one line below the other. Although in Messagebox.show I am coming accross  .Show($**"Data Exists in cells"). With this I found it difficult to syntax it. BTW How $ is helpful in messagebox

@SsD The $ is "helpful" when doing string interpolation. It's a way to format strings inline without &

Ok But How could I achieve the following Statements Data 6 exists in cell(0,0) Data 9 exists in cell(0,1) Data 7 exists in cell(0,2)...etc If your String interpolation could help to achieve the above .It would be Great. I tried but somewhere I am not able to put the number values after Data number value exists in cell (0,1)etc. This is my first time coming across string interpolation.

@SsD you are right, I didn't answer your question entirely, I was focused on making the code you posted work. You will want to return both the matched string and the cell for each match, so something like a struct, tuple, or class can help you achieve that.

You will want to return both the matched string and the cell for each match,  so something like a struct, tuple, or class can help you achieve that  How is this possible ?  what kind of Struct needs to be created ? What is Tuple ?

Hello  Any Progress ? I explored and learnt Basics about Tuple class with Basic Examples. Indeed Great. I went thru the following thread 33648402 of this forum . But it has completely gone over my head if the similar coding has to be applied in this case. Your insights and help will be appreciated.
